# How do I compare two arguments of an object to see if they are from the same object?

Tags: c#, object

I have to see if two arguments from an object are from the same object.
more specific i have a string and an image as arguments. Now I made 2 labels. one has the image and the other has the string in it.How do i  code something that tels me if the string of the label and the image of the other label are from the same object?

Comment: Consider showing a code example.  Presently, it is a bit difficult to know exactly what the problem is.

Comment: I do no think you can do that, at least with standard data types. A string/reference has no knowledge at runtime to which object it belongs.

Comment: If you just want to be sure that both parameters are from the same object, you could just use that object as parameter, and extract the members within your function.

Comment: you don't have to think in that way. Comparing a string with another string is much easier than checking if 2 arguments are of the same object. What I meant is give the picture a string id that's the same as the string of the first label, then compare them if they are same then they belong to the same object

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to want to do is preserve a reference to the string (path) of the image, such as C:\Users\USERNAME\Pictures\Random.jpg . You can then compare the Textbox string value with this reference.

Otherwise, you could alternatively load the image that your Textbox is pointing at, and compare the byte content with that of your PictureBox, although I would go with the first approach.

Other than this, there aren't really any easier, simpler or smarter ways to do it.